# When connecting Galaxy S2 to Eclipse LogCat begins to throw out errors like crazy

Tags: android, eclipse, logcat

Here is about a 1 second snapshot of everything written to logcat in verbose mode after plugging in my Galaxy SII (My app isn't even installed at this point).  I'm sure it's my phone since I tried plugging in another phone and even with my app running eclipse didn't have all these statements.  This started happening last night and since then I have restarted my machines, updated the sdks, removed apps that were updated within the last day, and made sure it wasn't my usb cable.

I'm about to try resetting to factory settings but before I do that I was wondering if there is anything else I could try since I am risking losing some of my contacts since I don't have space to back them all up on my sim card?

```
type=1, 1375283460.000000000
07-31 11:10:59.758: D/InputReader(2696): Input event: value=1
07-31 11:10:59.758: I/ScreenCaptureAction(2696): isHomeKeyPressed(), return value = false
07-31 11:10:59.758: D/KeyguardViewMediator(2696): onWakeKeyWhenKeyguardShowing(26)
07-31 11:10:59.758: D/KeyguardViewMediator(2696): wakeWhenReadyLocked(26)
07-31 11:10:59.758: D/KeyguardViewMediator(2696): handleWakeWhenReady(26)
07-31 11:10:59.758: D/KeyguardViewMediator(2696): pokeWakelock(5000)
07-31 11:10:59.758: D/PowerManagerService(2696): reactivateScreenLocksLocked mProxIgnoredBecauseScreenTurnedOff=false
07-31 11:10:59.763: E/lights(2696): write_int: path /sys/devices/virtual/misc/melfas_touchkey/brightness, value 1
07-31 11:10:59.763: E/power(2696): *** set_screen_state 1
07-31 11:10:59.763: D/SensorManager(2696): registerListener :: handle = 3  name= CM3663 Light Sensor delay= 200000 Listener= com.android.server.PowerManagerService$13@4052a538
07-31 11:10:59.763: D/PowerManagerService(2696): Screen__On : acquireWakeLock flags=0x1000001a tag=keyguard uid=1000 pid=2696   myUID=1000 myPID=2696 myTID=2763
07-31 11:10:59.763: I/PowerManagerService(2696): Ulight 0->7|0
07-31 11:10:59.763: D/PowerManagerService(2696): setLightBrightness : mButtonLight : 150
07-31 11:10:59.763: D/PowerManagerService(2696): enableLightSensor true
07-31 11:10:59.853: E/lights(2696): write_int: path /sys/class/backlight/pwm-backlight/brightness, value 7
07-31 11:10:59.853: D/PowerManagerService(2696): sendNotificationLocked on=true
07-31 11:10:59.858: D/KeyguardViewMediator(2696): onScreenTurnedOn, seq = 25
07-31 11:10:59.858: D/KeyguardViewMediator(2696): notifyScreenOnLocked
07-31 11:10:59.858: I/OrientationDebug(2696): [pwm] in updateOrientationListenerLp()
07-31 11:10:59.858: V/OrientationDebug(2696): in updateOrientationListenerLp(), Screen status=true, current orientation=5, SensorEnabled=false
07-31 11:10:59.858: I/OrientationDebug(2696): [pwm] needSensorRunningLp(), return false #3
07-31 11:10:59.858: D/PowerManagerService(2696): mNotificationTask : on
07-31 11:10:59.858: V/WindowManager(2696): Setting event dispatching to true
07-31 11:10:59.868: D/KeyguardViewMediator(2696): handleNotifyScreenOn
07-31 11:10:59.868: D/LockPatternKeyguardView(2696): onScreenTurnedOn()
07-31 11:10:59.868: I/LockPatternKeyguardView(2696): [MaxInactivityTime]onScreenTurnedOn: Entry
07-31 11:10:59.873: E/lights(2696): write_int: path /sys/class/backlight/pwm-backlight/brightness, value 15
07-31 11:10:59.873: I/LockPatternKeyguardView(2696): [MaxInactivityTime]onScreenTurnedOn: startTimer is called
07-31 11:10:59.878: D/LockPatternKeyguardView(2696): getTimeOutValue(FIX_GOOGLE_ISSUE) : getRequestedPasswordQuality=0
07-31 11:10:59.878: D/LockPatternKeyguardView(2696): getTimeOutValue() : _value=300000
07-31 11:10:59.878: I/LockPatternKeyguardView(2696): [MaxInactivityTime]startTimer: mInactivityTimeout=300000
07-31 11:10:59.878: I/LockPatternKeyguardView(2696): [MaxInactivityTime]startTimer: isInactivityTimeoutExpired is set to true
07-31 11:10:59.878: D/GlassLockScreenMusicWidget(2696): onPause()
07-31 11:10:59.878: D/GlassLockScreenMusicWidget(2696): stopMarguee()
07-31 11:10:59.878: D/GlassLockScreenMissedEventWidget(2696): onPause()
07-31 11:10:59.883: I/Launcher(2954): onResume(). mIsNewIntent : false screenOff: true
07-31 11:10:59.883: V/ProgramMonitor(2954): Binding::bindTaskManagerService() com.sec.android.widgetapp.programmonitorwidget.ProgramMonitorWidgetActivity$1@405e01b8 com.sec.android.app.controlpanel.service.ITaskManagerService$Stub$Proxy@4051eac0
07-31 11:10:59.888: E/lights(2696): write_int: path /sys/class/backlight/pwm-backlight/brightness, value 22
07-31 11:10:59.893: D/GlassLockScreenMusicWidget(2696): cleanUp()
07-31 11:10:59.893: D/GlassLockScreenMusicWidget(2696): stopMarguee()
07-31 11:10:59.893: D/GlassLockScreenMissedEventWidget(2696): cleanUp()
07-31 11:10:59.893: D/LockscreenWallpaperUpdater(2696): cleanUp()
07-31 11:10:59.893: D/GlassLockscreenInfo(2696): cleanUp()
07-31 11:10:59.893: D/LockPatternKeyguardView(2696): Face RecongnitionValue = 0
07-31 11:10:59.898: D/Launcher(2954): It's image wallpaper. suggestDesiredDimensions(-1,-1)
07-31 11:10:59.908: D/LockscreenWallpaperUpdater(2696): get drawable (public) 
07-31 11:10:59.908: D/LockscreenWallpaperUpdater(2696): get drawable (keygurardupdatemonitor private get) 
07-31 11:10:59.908: D/LockscreenWallpaperUpdater(2696): drawable is null(keygurardupdatemonitor private get) 
07-31 11:10:59.908: D/LockscreenWallpaperUpdater(2696): set drawable
07-31 11:10:59.908: D/LockscreenWallpaperUpdater(2696): wallpaper file not exist 
07-31 11:10:59.913: D/LockscreenWallpaperUpdater(2696): add lockscreenwallpaper
07-31 11:10:59.918: E/com.samsung.app(11344): [MSC]>>> WeatherWidgetProvider.java:316 [0:0] onReceive()@@@ sec.android.intent.action.HOME_RESUME
07-31 11:10:59.918: E/com.samsung.app(11344): [MSC]>>> WidgetIdManager.java:53 [0:0] AccuWeatherClockWidgetID_Length
07-31 11:10:59.918: E/com.samsung.app(11344): [MSC]>>> WidgetIdManager.java:54 [0:0] getPrefIDs() : length = 0
07-31 11:10:59.928: E/lights(2696): write_int: path /sys/class/backlight/pwm-backlight/brightness, value 30
07-31 11:10:59.943: E/com.samsung.app(11344): [MSC]>>> WeatherWidgetProvider.java:1634 [0:0] disable handler
07-31 11:10:59.943: E/com.samsung.app(11344): [MSC]>>> WeatherWidgetProvider.java:342 [0:0] The widget does not exist in idle!!
07-31 11:10:59.968: E/lights(2696): write_int: path /sys/class/backlight/pwm-backlight/brightness, value 37
07-31 11:10:59.983: E/lights(2696): write_int: path /sys/class/backlight/pwm-backlight/brightness, value 45
07-31 11:10:59.988: D/GlassLockScreenMusicWidget(2696): Controller Initiation Running!!
07-31 11:10:59.988: D/GlassLockScreenMusicWidget(2696): at init() send broadcast
07-31 11:10:59.988: D/GlassLockScreenMusicWidget(2696): resetMinTimer()
07-31 11:10:59.988: D/GlassLockScreenMusicWidget(2696): removeMinTimer()
07-31 11:10:59.988: D/GlassLockScreenMusicWidget(2696): addMinTimer()
07-31 11:10:59.988: D/GlassLockScreenMissedEventWidget(2696): Controller Initiation Running!!
07-31 11:10:59.988: D/GlassLockScreenMissedEventWidget(2696): updateMissedEvent(missed Call Count = 0, bUpdatedCallCount = false)
07-31 11:10:59.988: D/GlassLockScreenMissedEventWidget(2696): updateMissedEvent(Unread Msg Count = 0, bUpdatedMsgCount = false)
07-31 11:10:59.993: D/UnlockClock(2696): GMT_update mRightNow.getTimeZone().getID() == America/New_York
07-31 11:10:59.993: D/GlassLockscreenInfo(2696): init
07-31 11:10:59.998: D/InputReader(2696): Input event: value=0
07-31 11:10:59.998: I/ScreenCaptureAction(2696): isHomeKeyPressed(), return value = false
07-31 11:10:59.998: I/PhotoAppWidgetProvider(11365): onReceive
07-31 11:10:59.998: I/PhotoAppWidgetProvider(11365): RestartSlideShow
07-31 11:11:00.003: E/AlarmManagerService(2696): android_server_AlarmManagerService_set to type=1, 1375283476.827000000
07-31 11:11:00.003: D/PhotoDatabaseHelper(11365): getWidgetIdList query count : 0
07-31 11:11:00.003: D/PhotoAppWidgetProvider(11365): onReceive End
07-31 11:11:00.013: D/DigitalClock(9322): DigitalClockAppWidget.onReceive : ACTION_HOME_RESUME is called!!
07-31 11:11:00.023: D/GlassLockScreen(2696): CLOCK_POSITION from Setting Value = 2
07-31 11:11:00.023: I/LockPatternKeyguardView(2696): [MaxInactivityTime]startTimer: updateScreen(Lock) is called
07-31 11:11:00.033: E/lights(2696): write_int: path /sys/class/backlight/pwm-backlight/brightness, value 52
07-31 11:11:00.048: D/LockPatternKeyguardView(2696): getTimeOutValue(FIX_GOOGLE_ISSUE) : getRequestedPasswordQuality=0
07-31 11:11:00.048: D/LockPatternKeyguardView(2696): getTimeOutValue() : _value=300000
07-31 11:11:00.048: D/GlassLockScreenMusicWidget(2696): onPause()
07-31 11:11:00.048: D/GlassLockScreenMusicWidget(2696): stopMarguee()
07-31 11:11:00.048: D/GlassLockScreenMissedEventWidget(2696): onPause()
07-31 11:11:00.048: D/GlassLockScreenMusicWidget(2696): cleanUp()
07-31 11:11:00.048: D/GlassLockScreenMusicWidget(2696): stopMarguee()
07-31 11:11:00.048: D/GlassLockScreenMissedEventWidget(2696): cleanUp()
07-31 11:11:00.048: D/LockscreenWallpaperUpdater(2696): cleanUp()
07-31 11:11:00.048: D/GlassLockscreenInfo(2696): cleanUp()
07-31 11:11:00.048: D/LockPatternKeyguardView(2696): Face RecongnitionValue = 0
07-31 11:11:00.053: D/LockscreenWallpaperUpdater(2696): get drawable (public) 
07-31 11:11:00.053: D/LockscreenWallpaperUpdater(2696): get drawable (keygurardupdatemonitor private get) 
07-31 11:11:00.053: D/LockscreenWallpaperUpdater(2696): drawable is null(keygurardupdatemonitor private get) 
07-31 11:11:00.053: D/LockscreenWallpaperUpdater(2696): set drawable
07-31 11:11:00.053: D/LockscreenWallpaperUpdater(2696): wallpaper file not exist 
07-31 11:11:00.053: D/LockscreenWallpaperUpdater(2696): add lockscreenwallpaper
07-31 11:11:00.053: D/GlassLockScreenMusicWidget(2696): Controller Initiation Running!!
07-31 11:11:00.053: D/GlassLockScreenMusicWidget(2696): at init() send broadcast
07-31 11:11:00.053: D/GlassLockScreenMusicWidget(2696): resetMinTimer()
07-31 11:11:00.053: D/GlassLockScreenMusicWidget(2696): removeMinTimer()
07-31 11:11:00.053: D/GlassLockScreenMusicWidget(2696): addMinTimer()
07-31 11:11:00.058: E/lights(2696): write_int: path /sys/class/backlight/pwm-backlight/brightness, value 60
07-31 11:11:00.063: D/GlassLockScreenMissedEventWidget(2696): Controller Initiation Running!!
07-31 11:11:00.063: D/GlassLockScreenMissedEventWidget(2696): updateMissedEvent(missed Call Count = 0, bUpdatedCallCount = false)
07-31 11:11:00.063: D/GlassLockScreenMissedEventWidget(2696): updateMissedEvent(Unread Msg Count = 0, bUpdatedMsgCount = false)
07-31 11:11:00.068: I/OrientationDebug(2696): [WindowOrientationListener] in enable(), now call SensorManager.registerListener()
07-31 11:11:00.068: D/SensorManager(2696): registerListener :: handle = 0  name= K3DH Acceleration Sensor delay= 200000 Listener= android.view.WindowOrientationListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@40905ac8
07-31 11:11:00.068: D/UnlockClock(2696): GMT_update mRightNow.getTimeZone().getID() == America/New_York
07-31 11:11:00.068: D/MotionRecognitionService(2696):   .initializeMotionEngine
07-31 11:11:00.073: E/lights(2696): write_int: path /sys/class/backlight/pwm-backlight/brightness, value 67
07-31 11:11:00.078: D/GlassLockscreenInfo(2696): init
07-31 11:11:00.078: D/GlassLockScreen(2696): CLOCK_POSITION from Setting Value = 2
07-31 11:11:00.078: D/LockscreenWallpaperUpdater(2696): onResume()
07-31 11:11:00.083: D/UnlockClock(2696): GMT_update mRightNow.getTimeZone().getID() == America/New_York
07-31 11:11:00.083: D/GlassLockScreenMusicWidget(2696): onResume() isTopLayout=true, isMaxLayout=true
07-31 11:11:00.083: D/GlassLockScreenMusicWidget(2696): mHeightDifference = 0
07-31 11:11:00.083: D/GlassLockScreenMusicWidget(2696): onResume()show
07-31 11:11:00.083: D/GlassLockScreenMusicWidget(2696): setMaxLayout()
07-31 11:11:00.083: D/GlassLockScreenMusicWidget(2696): startTranslateAnimation()
07-31 11:11:00.083: D/GlassLockScreenMusicWidget(2696): resetMinTimer()
07-31 11:11:00.083: D/GlassLockScreenMusicWidget(2696): removeMinTimer()
07-31 11:11:00.083: D/GlassLockScreenMusicWidget(2696): addMinTimer()
07-31 11:11:00.083: D/GlassLockScreenMissedEventWidget(2696): onResume()
07-31 11:11:00.083: D/GlassLockScreenMissedEventWidget(2696): updateMissedEvent(missed Call Count = 0, bUpdatedCallCount = false)
07-31 11:11:00.083: D/GlassLockScreenMissedEventWidget(2696): updateMissedEvent(Unread Msg Count = 0, bUpdatedMsgCount = false)
07-31 11:11:00.083: D/GlassLockscreenInfo(2696): onResume()
07-31 11:11:00.083: D/LockPatternKeyguardView(2696): mLockScreen instanceof GlassLockScreen
07-31 11:11:00.083: D/GlassLockScreen(2696): setScreenOn() mGlassLockScreenMusicWidget=com.android.internal.policy.impl.GlassLockScreenMusicWidget@40cd18d8
07-31 11:11:00.083: D/LockscreenWallpaperUpdater(2696): onResume()
07-31 11:11:00.083: D/UnlockClock(2696): GMT_update mRightNow.getTimeZone().getID() == America/New_York
07-31 11:11:00.088: E/lights(2696): write_int: path /sys/class/backlight/pwm-backlight/brightness, value 75
07-31 11:11:00.088: I/StatusBarPolicy(2846): onDataActivity-D:0
07-31 11:11:00.093: D/GlassLockScreenMusicWidget(2696): onResume() isTopLayout=true, isMaxLayout=true
07-31 11:11:00.093: D/GlassLockScreenMusicWidget(2696): mHeightDifference = 0
07-31 11:11:00.093: D/GlassLockScreenMusicWidget(2696): onResume()show
07-31 11:11:00.093: D/GlassLockScreenMusicWidget(2696): setMaxLayout()
07-31 11:11:00.093: D/GlassLockScreenMusicWidget(2696): startTranslateAnimation()
07-31 11:11:00.093: D/GlassLockScreenMusicWidget(2696): resetMinTimer()
07-31 11:11:00.093: D/GlassLockScreenMusicWidget(2696): removeMinTimer()
07-31 11:11:00.093: D/GlassLockScreenMusicWidget(2696): addMinTimer()
07-31 11:11:00.093: D/GlassLockScreenMissedEventWidget(2696): onResume()
07-31 11:11:00.093: D/GlassLockScreenMissedEventWidget(2696): updateMissedEvent(missed Call Count = 0, bUpdatedCallCount = false)
07-31 11:11:00.093: D/GlassLockScreenMissedEventWidget(2696): updateMissedEvent(Unread Msg Count = 0, bUpdatedMsgCount = false)
07-31 11:11:00.093: I/StatusBarPolicy(2846): onDataActivity-D:0
07-31 11:11:00.098: D/GlassLockscreenInfo(2696): onResume()
07-31 11:11:00.108: D/SurfaceFlinger(2696): Screen about to return, flinger = 0x91840
07-31 11:11:00.108: E/lights(2696): write_int: path /sys/class/backlight/pwm-backlight/brightness, value 82
07-31 11:11:00.118: D/FastDormancy(2895): [FD] INTENT ACTION android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON
07-31 11:11:00.118: D/FastDormancy(2895): [FD] mIsScreenOn: true
07-31 11:11:00.123: D/PhoneUtils(2895): updateRAFT() : FactoryMode : false
07-31 11:11:00.123: D/WallpaperService(2696): ACTION_SCREEN_ON
07-31 11:11:00.123: D/WallpaperService(2696): mVisible:true
07-31 11:11:00.123: D/WallpaperService(2696): mScreenOn:true
07-31 11:11:00.123: D/WallpaperService(2696): mReportedVisible:false
07-31 11:11:00.128: E/lights(2696): write_int: path /sys/class/backlight/pwm-backlight/brightness, value 90
07-31 11:11:00.138: I/System.out(3865): pressed power button:---0
07-31 11:11:00.138: D/WispService(3436): main:Active wifi network is connected
07-31 11:11:00.153: D/WispService(3436): main:Wifi ssid is: SWEETH
07-31 11:11:00.153: D/WispService(3436): main:Not matching: Wayport_Access
07-31 11:11:00.153: D/WispService(3436): main:Not matching: ATTMETROWIFI
07-31 11:11:00.153: D/WispService(3436): main:Not matching: attwifi
07-31 11:11:00.153: D/WispService(3436): main:Not matching: AT&T Wi-Fi
07-31 11:11:00.153: D/WispService(3436): main:No Wisp network found
07-31 11:11:00.153: D/WispService(3436): main:Moving from: DISCONNECTED to CONNECTED
07-31 11:11:00.158: D/WispService(3436): main:Wifi ssid is: SWEETH
07-31 11:11:00.158: D/WispService(3436): main:Not matching: Wayport_Access
07-31 11:11:00.158: D/WispService(3436): main:Not matching: ATTMETROWIFI
07-31 11:11:00.158: D/WispService(3436): main:Not matching: attwifi
07-31 11:11:00.158: D/WispService(3436): main:Not matching: AT&T Wi-Fi
07-31 11:11:00.158: D/WispService(3436): main:No Wisp network found
07-31 11:11:00.158: D/WispService(3436): main:Moving from: CONNECTED to DISCONNECTED
07-31 11:11:00.158: D/WispService(3436): main:Resetting response manager
07-31 11:11:00.168: E/lights(2696): write_int: path /sys/class/backlight/pwm-backlight/brightness, value 97
07-31 11:11:00.188: E/lights(2696): write_int: path /sys/class/backlight/pwm-backlight/brightness, value 105
07-31 11:11:00.198: D/Buddies--------------------------->(11373): Service:OnReceive ACTION_HOME_RESUME called
07-31 11:11:00.203: E/lights(2696): write_int: path /sys/class/backlight/pwm-backlight/brightness, value 112
```

Comment: I don't see any exceptions, just a lot of logging. If you have installed any new applications recently, it is possible that those applications are just over-logging.

Comment: I get that which is why I deleted any apps that updated around the time logcat started going nuts.  I can't delete the samsung widgets which looks to be throwing a lot, any other thoughts on things to try?

Comment: Use the logcat filtering that is included with both ADT for Eclipse and Android Studio. It doesn't matter how much other applications log if you are only looking at the logs for your app.

Answer (score 0):

This is `LogCat` not `ErrorCat`. What you see is system log so most of the information there are log entries. Only those with `E/` are errors but it again - does not mean anything unless you know what this particular log entry is all about.

Read about what log is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logfile and then about Android logging to get wider picture: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html

Answer (score 0):

I reset the phone to factory settings and the logcat stopped reporting so many things. It's not my 1st choice because it's kind of a pain to set everything up again, but it works.

Comment: In hindsight I think I might have deleted the filter in elcipse that shows just the debug from my app.  I had the same problem today and it was because I accidentally deleted the filter.